# find shortest length of a isosceles trapezoid

Tags: trigonometry

Im not sure if this question is easy or not, the concept of what I'm asking seems simple but I cant figure it out.

[image]

Given that A0 = 100, and h = 10, how would I calculate Az.

[image]

I have begun by trying to calculate 'x' and then obtain the slope from this but I dont know if I'm over complicating the situation. Can anyone suggest a method for this?

Comment: The best you can do is write $AZ=100-2x$. Are you trying to find the minimum value of the perimeter of such a trapezoid? If so, note the length of the left/right side is, by the Pythagorean Theorem, $\sqrt{10^2+x^2}$.

Comment: What keeps $Az$ from being zero (or arbitrarily close to it)?  You need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am trying to calculate the volume of water in a theoretical lake where as h (the lake depth) increases Az decreases (assuming a conical shaped lake). From your comments I gather that I need the slope (angle), which I could take to be anything really.